# Find and Execute Scripts in Subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a filesystem structured like this:

- Parent Directory

  - orchestrator

    - init.sh
  - Subdir1

    - install.sh
  - Subdir2

    - install.sh
  - Subdir3

    - install.sh

Within the init.sh, I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

######################
# Run all installers #
######################

cd "$(dirname $0)"/..

# find the installers and run them interatively
find ../ -name install.sh -type f -exec chmod a+x {} \;
find . -name install.sh | while read installer ; do sh -c "${installer}" ; done
```

This works for the most part, but it is fragile. If one of the install.sh scripts encounters a problem, the init.sh script stops. I'd like for it to continue on to the next install.sh script if this happens. But I'm not sure how to get that to work.

Comment: Try removing `set -e` and see what happens. You're telling the script to abort on error and that's what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `sh -c "${installer}"` with  `sh -c "${installer} || true"` should work, since `true` always returns 0.